# How do I simulate mouse right click from Keyboard?

Tags: mouse

I have only a keyboard attached to my Raspberry Pi. How do I simulate a mouse right click from keyboard itself?

I tried various keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and also the right click button in my keyboard, but nothing seems to be working.

I am running the latest version of Raspbian.

Comment: what prevents you from connecting a mouse to RasPi?

Comment: I have connected a pen drive in the other USB port and if connect my USB hub, then I need to provide extra power to it :(

Comment: there are wireless mouse/keyboard combos, that will occupy only one USB slot for wireless module.

Comment: @lenik Yeah I am not denying any of that. But right now, all I need is to just simulate the right click. If I can do that, then I can start using Raspberry Pi for my presentations, without any additional hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can install a command line tool xdotool that will emulate the click for you.
Should be installed on the Pi by default.

http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

Navigate using Arrow keys.

- Hit the "OK" key to select

or

- Hit the "C" key to bring up the Context-Menu

Works on my Ras Pi 2 with OpenElec.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please note that you can always edit your own posts, in this case the first answer of yours. I suggest to merge both posts into one comprehensive, well formated answer.